# Cannot retrieve user ID before calling another Observable which requires the ID - Angularfire2

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am performing an operation in angularfire2 where I subscribe to angularfire.auth in order to retrieve the user id for the currently signed in user using the following code:

```
angularfire.auth.subscribe(auth => {
      this.userId = auth.uid;
      console.log(this.userId);
  }
```

This works successfully and assigns the uid to the local variable userId.

The problem I am having is when I wish to perform the following code:

```
let shipObservable = angularfire.database.list('/ships/' + this.userId);

    shipObservable.subscribe(
        value => {
            this.otherObservable = angularfire.database.list('/other/' + value[0].otherId);
            this.otherObservable.subscribe(value => {
                this.address = value[0].$value;
                this.number = value[1].$value;
                this.email = value[2].$value;
                this.name = value[3].$value;
                });
    }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

The issue is that the second piece of code runs before I get the uid back from the first observable. I am aware that these are asynchronous operations and may come back at anytime. But I would like to know is there a way to ensure that the second observable executes **after** the user id has been assigned to the uid returned by auth.

Comment: AngularFire returns a promise now.

Comment: @CorySilva Which part of it is returning a promise? Was this a recent update?

Comment: I was looking for the subscribe method and cannot find it...  Nor do I remember it.  What version are you using?  The promise I referenced is described [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebaseobject-value)

Comment: As far as I know angularfire.auth is an observable. I am using angularfire 2 version 2.0.0-beta.3-pre2

Comment: Lol nevermind; I did not notice you were using AngularFire2/ecmascript 6.  I should have realized when I saw the subscribe method...  duh.

Comment: No problem. So are you familiar with how I would solve my issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem using the [switchMap operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) which is part of RXJS. In the snippet below I assume that 'afAuth' is a reference to the firebase auth object and 'af' is a reference to the firebase database object.

```
authState$ = afAuth.authState;
shipObservable$ = authState$.switchMap((auth) => {
    return af.list('ships/' + auth.uid);
});
```

To use switchMap you need to import the operator:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
```